# how to get button to show up inside Jade table?

Tags: pug

I'm trying to convert html pages to Jade. I can't get some buttons to show up inside a td. (Working on an Angular app.)

Table without buttons shows up fine.

```
tr(ng-repeat='local in locals |  orderBy:predicate | filter:query')
  td {{local.points}}
  td {{local.lastname}}
  td {{local.firstname}}
  td {{local.zip}}
```

Table with buttons won't compile.

```
tr(ng-repeat='local in locals |  orderBy:predicate | filter:query')
  td
    button(ng-click='local.points = local.points + 10')
    button(ng-click='local.points = local.points - 10') {{local.points}}
  td {{local.lastname}}
  td {{local.firstname}}
  td {{local.zip}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Jade is expecting a value for the button. This worked for that td

```
td
  button( ng-click='local.points = local.points + 10') Up
  button(ng-click='local.points = local.points - 10') Dn
  {{local.points}}
```